# Not able to post Excel or Word Files in Solr 6.3.0, where to change the configuration

Tags: solr, apache-tika

While trying to post any  Excel/Word/Pdf files, solr responds with

```
Unsupported ContentType: application/vnd.ms-excel  Not in: [application/xml, application/csv, application/json, text/json, text/csv, text/xml, application/javabin]
```

What needs to be changed and where

Comment: Can you please explain what you have tried to solve this issue before posting it on SO? We'd need to see what possible solutions did not work in your case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dauto` while you posting files.

Example

```
java -Dauto -Dc=gettingstarted -jar post.jar *
```

`-Dauto` supports all documents which apache tika can hanlde(pdf,html,etc..)

Find out more using help(-h)

```
Java -jar post.jar -h
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had to change  -Durl from http://localhost:8983/solr/update to http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract

Comment: welcome. please upvote, accept if you found my answer helpful.